# Django: Change Queryset of already defined Prefetch object

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm, prefetch

#### Context

I really want to, but I don't understand how I can limit an already existing Prefetch object

#### Models

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Absence(Model):
    employee = ForeignKey(MyUser, related_name='absences', on_delete=PROTECT)
    start_date = DateField()
    end_date = DateField()
```

#### View

```
class UserAbsencesListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = MyUser.objects.order_by('first_name')
    serializer_class = serializers.UserWithAbsencesSerializer
    filterset_class = filters.UserAbsencesFilterSet
```

#### Filter

```
class UserAbsencesFilterSet(FilterSet):
    first_name = CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', field_name='first_name')
    from_ = DateFilter(method='filter_from', distinct=True)
    to = DateFilter(method='filter_to', distinct=True)
```

#### What do I need

With the Request there are two arguments `from_` and `to`. I should return Users with their Absences, which (Absences) are bounded by `from_` and/or `to` intervals. It's very simple for a single argument, i can limit the set using `Prefetch` object:

```
def filter_from(self, queryset, name, value):
    return queryset.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'absences',
            Absence.objects.filter(Q(start_date__gte=value) | Q(start_date__lte=value, end_date__gte=value)),
        )
    )
```

Similarly for `to`.

But what if I want to get a limit by two arguments at once?
When the `from_` attribute is requested - 'filter_from' method is executed; for the `to` argument, another method `filter_to` is executed.

I can't use `prefetch_related` twice, I get an exception `ValueError: 'absences' lookup was already seen with a different queryset. You may need to adjust the ordering of your lookups.`.

I've tried using `to_attr`, but it looks like I can't access it in an un-evaluated queryset.

I know that I can find the first defined `Prefetch` in the `_prefetch_related_lookups` attribute of queryset, but is there any way to apply an additional filter to it or replace it with another `Prefetch` object so that I can end up with a query similar to:

```
queryset.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'absences',
        Absence.objects.filter(
            Q(Q(start_date__gte=from_) | Q(start_date__lte=from_, end_date__gte=from_))
            & Q(Q(end_date__lte=to) | Q(start_date__lte=to, end_date__gte=to))
        ),
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`django-filter` seems to have its own built-in filter for range queries:

More info [here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html?highlight=range#datefromtorangefilter) and [here](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/f4866a9852d569861651cc733f909fe0e378131b/django_filters/filters.py#L413)

So probably just easier to use that instead:

```py
def filter_date_range(self, queryset, name, value):
    if self.lookup_expr = "range":
        #return queryset with specific prefetch 
    if self.lookup_expr = "lte":
        #return queryset with specific prefetch 
    if self.lookup_expr = "gte":
        #return queryset with specific prefetch
```

I haven't tested this and you may need to play around with the unpacking of [value](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/f4866a9852d569861651cc733f909fe0e378131b/django_filters/filters.py#L420) but it should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

I'm familiar with this field, but due to the desire of front-end developers, I have to use two separate attributes with specific names, rather than one with suffixes.

I'm currently using a function that the filter methods call and get the attribute data from `self.form.cleaned_data.get('attribute_name')` but I don't really like this solution.

Comment: I suppose you could try clearing the queryset of prefetches and then apply another `cleared_qs = qs.prefetch_related(None)`

Comment: I didn’t even imagine such an opportunity as resetting `prefetch_related`. And although this does not solve my problem completely, it helps a lot in solving it by simplifying the code.
Thank you!